# Accessing React Router Context

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router, react-context

[image]

[image]

How would I access context in my application?. I ran into a react-router and redux error where I wasn't getting my route path from the state and because of that I wasn't getting match.props so I could set the path. My aim is to usu context to set my route path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's generally not a good idea to store the navigation state in Redux.

You can access data from the react-router context using the hooks `useHistory`, `useLocation`, `useParams`, and `useRouteMatch`.

Probably this is what you want, it returns the current path like `"/users/joe"`:

```
const {pathname} = useLocation();
```

If you want path template that was matched by the `Route` , like `"/users/:username"`, then you would use:

```
const {path} = useRouteMatch();
```

Comment: How can I do it dynamically without creating different files for different routes?

Comment: Can you explain better what you mean?  These hooks `useLocation` and `useRouteMatch` are dynamic for the current page.  You can create a custom hook that uses these but I'm not sure what your actual goal is.